# Animating the XY position of SVG text using JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, svg

So, this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/fireshark/pen/oavVVQ) shows an attempted XY animation of a circle and text using javascript to set a new position of both the circle and text elements.

The circle animates as expected but the text just jumps to the new position.

HTML...

```
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="#c0c0c0"/>
  <text x="50" y="50">Hello</text>
</svg>
<div>
  <button>Animate</button>
</div>
```

CSS...

```
svg {
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
}
circle,text {
  transition: 1.0s;  
}
```

Javascript...

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('circle').setAttribute('cx', 200);
  document.querySelector('text').setAttribute('x', 200);
})
```

Is there a way to set a new XY position on the text via javascript that causes a nice animation between the current position and new position (like is happening for the circle)?  To be clear, I'd prefer not to animate this via javascript if possible (other than setting the end position).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check your example in Firefox the circle is not animated either. In fact coordinates are not animatable (yet?) with CSS. In order to animate the circle and the text with CSS I would use transforms:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('circle').style.transform="translateX(150px)";
  document.querySelector('text').style.transform="translateX(150px)";
})
```

```css
svg {
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
}
circle,text {
  transform:translateX(0);
  transition: all 1.0s;  
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="#c0c0c0"/>
  <text x="50" y="50">Hello</text>
</svg>
<div>
  <button>Animate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: There we go, I like that answer.  I had tried something similar but tried using translate() instead of translateX() and translateY().  Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this through CSS: CSS animations only work for CSS (surprise) whereas what you're trying to animate are SVG properties.

Make your JS insert/update an [AnimateTransform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform) element associated with your rect instead, which is SVG's built-in way of animating content.

Comment: So, I'm using Vue to set the XY position (didn't show in example as it makes the example more complex) of these SVG elements.  You'd recommend that instead of setting the XY positions directly, I watch for the XY positions to change and if they change create a child AnimateTransform each time (perhaps destroying any existing child AnimateTransform if one already exists) to move to the new XY position?

Comment: Make vue set `transform="translate(..., ...)"` instead of the `cx` and `cy` attributes (just ensure they're set to 0 when you make the element), and then use AnimateTransform to animate the transform.

Comment: alternatively, you could define _two_ regular [animate elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate), one for `cx` and one for `cy`, but if you're doing 2D animation, using the `transform` attribute is kind of literally what it was invented for.

Comment: So, I realize you recommended against CSS but I did see that changing everything to use transform=translate() allowed both the text and circle to animate just using the CSS transition property -- see https://codepen.io/fireshark/pen/ePOqWr.  I guess I'm gambling with browser support doing it this way?

Comment: Yeah, even Firefox doesn't animate using that CSS property.  Guess that isn't the way despite Chrome working fine.

Comment: Never trust just Chrome. If you can, make sure it works in Chrome, and Firefox, and Edge. SVG is a complete vector graphics solution on its own, that happens to now be allowed in HTML5 documents without crazy xml namespace nonsense, but it still doesn't like to play nice with CSS. By design. So whenever you need to do "a thing" in SVG, it's a good bet SVG already has its own way for you to do that.

Comment: @KJohnson Please check the support for SMIL animations like `<animate>` https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil